# 2d surface plot in matplotlib with an irregullar data grid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot some data on a 2D surface plot. The data represents variation in properties over a T shape sample. However the method I'm using (standard method from documentation) interpolates over an entire square grid, going beyond where the T component dimentsions.

I want to restrict the interpolation to within the T component.

I am assuming this is done by defining a T shape grid (or whatever shape you want to interpolate over) is this correct? and if so how would I go about creating a T shaped grid to interpolate over? I'm thinking appending 2 `linspace` arrays together to create the T shape, but failing massively so far =/

Many thanks!

Edit 1)

normal grid:

```
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

shape of area I want to interpolate over:

```
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
000xxx000
000xxx000
```

with `x`= data points to interpolate over and `0`s representing voids which shouldnt contain any interpolation.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to do a surface plot (in 3D, like from `Axes3D.plot_surface`), or a 2D image with a colormap (like in `imshow`)?

Comment: I have been using an `imshow` colour map and the data points are layed out as showing in the edit above:

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the array you want to show with `np.nan`:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a = np.random.rand(100, 100)
>>> plt.imshow(a)
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x03EEB030>
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

And now:

```
>>> a[50:, :25] = np.nan
>>> a[50:, 75:] = np.nan
>>> plt.imshow(a)
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x040C81B0>
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]